# Returning a custom List of 2 columns from EF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have an application that basically stores files on a server and records details in a database. Another app runs on a daily basis to look for "orphaned" files.  The table that holds the details has 2 columns (relevant to this) `TransId` and `SurvId`.  The files are held in a folder structure where many `SurvId` are countained within `TransId`:

```
C:\Files\23\1
C:\Files\23\2
C:\Files\23\3
C:\Files\23\4
C:\Files\24\1
C:\Files\24\2
C:\Files\24\3
```

What I need to do now is check that these exist in the database.  Data access is through a WCF web service and that uses EF to query the database.

So the first option I can see is to call the web service and return a list or unique records `TransId, SurvId`, loop through the folders and use Linq on the List to check they exist.

The second option is to loop through the folders and make a separate call to the web service to check for existence.

This process runs overnight while the system has no user load. Option 1 means one call to the web service but could, potentially, return a list of 200K records or more.  The second returns a boolean but means the webservice could be called 200k times (or more).

I guess a third option would be a split between the two and call the web service for each `TransId`.

Anyway I am in the process of trying each method but have run into this problem on option 1....

My method in the web service:

```
    public List<MyFolderCheck> GetTransSurvids()
    {
        List<MyFolderCheck> response = new List<MyFolderCheck>();

            var DbContext = new MyDataStorageEntities();

            var dataset =
            (from recordset in DbContext.MySurvs

             select new MyFolderCheck
             {
                 transId = recordset.TransactionId,
                 survId = recordset.SurvId
             }).ToList();

            response = dataset;

        return response;
    }
```

The call to this returns the correct number of elements in the list but I can only see `TransId`

Comment: Do you have `SurvId` data in table? Do you have correct mapping of MySurv entity?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes both TransId and SurvId are not null in the schema.  If I select all records in SSMS both columns are populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> returns the correct number of elements in the list but I can only see TransId

It looks like you forgot to decorate `survId` in `MyFolderCheck` with `[DataMember]` attribute. The data would be correct on the server, but if only `transId` has a `[DataMember]` on it, you'd see empty `survId`s on the receiving end.